# How to delete files using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I tried to delete file from specific directory(Folder) but it doesn't work for me

this is my code

```
DeletePhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
                {
                    PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,

                });


                if ( file != null)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(file.Path))
                    {
                        DependencyService.Get<IFileManager>().DeleteFile(file.Path);
                    }
                    file.Dispose();

                }
            };
```

In android

```
  public class FileManager : IFileManager
        {
            public void DeleteFile(string source)
            {
                File.Delete(source);
            }
        }
```

IFileManager Interface

```
 public interface IFileManager
    {
        void DeleteFile(string source);
    }
```

In mainfest permisson is given but something didn't happen and i find the file which i deleted

Comment: have you stepped through the code to verify that DeleteFile() is actually getting called?  Have you checked for errors or exceptions?

Comment: No exceptions and yes , delete file is called with the right path

Comment: @Jason I Found that file is stored in internal storage does it make difference or it's the same ? how can i use internal permission ?

Comment: I have posted an answer, please try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by `PickPhotoAsync()`method, this method is saving a COPY of the image in the blow directory:

```
"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{package name}/files/Pictures/temp/***.jpg"
```

you can debug to find this and you can check this issue of MediaPlugin by [this](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/441)

So when you use `PickPhotoAsync()`method to select a file, the actual file you have deleted is the copy in the `temp` directory.

If you want to delete the original file, you will have to change the parameter of

`DeleteFile(string source)`   method to the original path as follows:

```
string path= "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{package name}/files/Pictures/Test/***.jpg";

DeleteFile(path);
```

Comment: I did this but doesn't work for me .. any solution ?

Comment: I Tried to change path as you said it deleted file from gallery only but doesn't made it from temp files , but anyway it works thank you

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me , You'll some dependency injection on android:

`using Android.Content;
using Android.Provider;
using System;`

```
     public bool DeleteFile(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
            Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(filePath);

            string where = MediaStore.MediaColumns.Data + "=?";
            string[] selectionArgs = new string[] { file.AbsolutePath };
            ContentResolver contentResolver = context.ContentResolver;
            Android.Net.Uri filesUri = MediaStore.Files.GetContentUri("external");

            if (file.Exists())
            {
                contentResolver.Delete(filesUri, where, selectionArgs);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
            return false;
        }
    }
```