# Xamarin Forms Android can't delete image from gallery or App folders with no error displayed

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms Android App and I can't delete images from gallery or App folders using the App. No error displays after failure. I am targeting Android 10.0. Relevant code is below:

\Interface

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace TCmTickets
{
    public interface IDeleteFromFile
    {
        void DeleteFile(string source);
    }
}
```

\Class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(TCmTickets.Droid.DeleFromFile))]
namespace TCmTickets.Droid
{

    class DeleFromFile : IDeleteFromFile
    {
        public void DeleteFile(string source)
        {
            File.Delete(source);
        }
    }
}
```

\MainActivity

```
    DependencyService.Register <DeleFromFile>();

    DependencyService.Get<DeleFromFile>();
```

\Function

```
private async void DeleteFileTest()
{
    var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
    {
        PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,
    });


    if (file != null)
    {
        if (File.Exists(file.Path))
        {
            DependencyService.Get<IDeleteFromFile>().DeleteFile(file.Path);
        }
        file.Dispose();
    }
}


void btnDeleteFile_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DeleteFileTest();
}
```

Could this have something to do with Android 10. I am using the correct permissions - I have included the following in Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.TCmTickets" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="25" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="TCmTickets.Android" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="xxxx" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Any ideas @Tom0x

Comment: Any ideas @FreakyAli

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you "can't" delete files? Get an error? What does the error say? No error at all, just doesn't delete...?

Comment: @ChrisBaker no error at all. Just doesn't delete for some reason

Comment: Interesting. I would include that specifically in your question (not everyone reads the comments, years of using Youtube has trained us not to haha)

Comment: please check this link:- <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54330202/how-to-delete-files-using-xamarin-forms>